# How an assignment is a lambda in kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

In order to implement [`Handler().postDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) I need to add a `Runnable` object in the first parameter of `postDelayed()`:

```
private fun blankFields() {
    blank_fields_error.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Handler().postDelayed({blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}, 5000)
}
```

I'm trying to understand how `{blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}` is a lambda simply because it's wrapped in `{}`. Does that mean any assignment can be a lambda if wrapped in `{}`?

Comment: This magic is called SAM conversion and it works with Java interfaces and otherwise with Kotlin functional types (and typealiases of functional types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `{}` is a short version of

```
{ (parameters) /* From 0 to n */ ->
   // Deal with it
}
```

that `parameter` can be replaced with keyword **it** since it's only one parameter and doesn't need to be displayed though (If there's only one param).

In your case `{}` has no arguments. So it will be a no parameter function.

In Kotlin a lambda is a function used as another function parameter (a
 higher order function).

In your case that lambda is a function representing a runnable interface (note that it is a function if you are using Kotlin). And `postDelayed` takes one `()->Unit` which is runnable, and a long value.

Comment: "A simple {} is a short version of" Not quite, this depends on context. And for `Runnable` in particular, there's no parameter.

Comment: So because there is one method in `Runnable`, `run()`, does that mean `{blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}` is the body content for `run()`?

Answer (score 3):

Any *code* is a lambda if it's wrapped in curly braces. A lambda is an anonymous function, with a parameter list that may be omitted in some cases. Whatever code you place in these braces (after the parameter list) is the body of the function.

That may be a single statement or expression:

```
{ println("Hello") }
{ a = 1 }
```

Or as many lines of code as you like:

```
{
    println(1)
    println(2)
    println(3)
}
```

I recommend looking at the [official documentation about lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) for more information.